# How to reinstall Terraria on Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues, terraria

I recently added unsupported files to my Terraria and edited my files. This was a error on my part because now Terraria won't load.

I have no way to fix this and am not good enough at file programming to fix it with any hardcore methods.

My biggest problem is that I don't know how to delete and reinstall the game. I looked it up and it told me that there was a way to delete it in the launcher, but gave no clear way how to get there. I may have looked this up incorrectly or been looking untrustworthy websites.

How can I re-install Terraria?

Comment: You can probably make your question a bit more clear. "How can I reinstall Terraria?" would probably be a better title. You should also probably mention what platform the game is through. If you are on Steam @Chippies 's answer is correct, but if you got the game through GoG, then the steps differ.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: Spending a bit of time on a descriptive title and a clear problem will set you in very good stead here at Arqade. We like it when users out in time and effort, both when asking and answering questions. Not doing so will lead to downvotes and close votes for unclear questions.

Comment: Awesome. Your question looks much better now. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to verify file integrity, which will automatically re-download missing or edited files.
Here's how you do it:

1. Right click on Terraria in your library and go to Properties
   [image]
2. Now go to Local Files tab and click on Verify File Integrity
   [image]
3. Wait until it's done verifying and after it's done, your game should
   work.

If this method doesn't work, you have to Right click on Terraria in Library and click on Delete Local Content, which will uninstall the game. For extra measure you could delete the  whole Terraria folder (your worlds and characters are saved in a different folder) and then just install it again like you usually would.